# Как подружить Gulp и его browser-sync с PHP?

Tags: php, gulp, препроцессор, browsersync

Как подружить Gulp и его browser-sync с PHP? ЧТО НАДО ПОМЕНЯТЬ В gulpfile.js чтобы он обновлял страницу при изменении php

```js
var syntax         = 'sass', // Syntax: sass or scss;
  gulpVersion    = '4'; // Gulp version: 3 or 4
  gmWatch        = false; // ON/OFF GraphicsMagick watching "img/_src" folder (true/false). Linux install gm: sudo apt update; sudo apt install graphicsmagick

var gulp          = require('gulp'),
  gutil         = require('gulp-util' ),
  sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
  browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
  concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
  cleancss      = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  rename        = require('gulp-rename'),
  autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  notify        = require('gulp-notify'),
  rsync         = require('gulp-rsync'),
  imageResize   = require('gulp-image-resize'),
  imagemin      = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  del           = require('del');

// Local Server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
 browserSync({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'app'
  },
  notify: false,
  // open: false,
  // online: false, // Work Offline Without Internet Connection
  // tunnel: true, tunnel: "projectname", // Demonstration page: http://projectname.localtunnel.me
 })
});

// Sass|Scss Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/'+syntax+'/**/*.'+syntax+'')
 .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on("error", notify.onError()))
 .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min', prefix : '' }))
 .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
 .pipe(cleancss( {level: { 1: { specialComments: 0 } } })) // Opt., comment out when debugging
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

// JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
 return gulp.src([
  'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'app/js/common.js', // Always at the end
  ])
 .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
 // .pipe(uglify()) // Mifify js (opt.)
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

// HTML Live Reload
gulp.task('code', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/*.html')
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

// Deploy
gulp.task('rsync', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/**')
 .pipe(rsync({
  root: 'app/',
  hostname: 'username@yousite.com',
  destination: 'yousite/public_html/',
  // include: ['*.htaccess'], // Includes files to deploy
  exclude: ['**/Thumbs.db', '**/*.DS_Store'], // Excludes files from deploy
  recursive: true,
  archive: true,
  silent: false,
  compress: true
 }))
});

// Images @x1 & @x2 + Compression | Required graphicsmagick (sudo apt update; sudo apt install graphicsmagick)
gulp.task('img1x', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/img/_src/**/*.*')
 .pipe(imageResize({ width: '50%' }))
 .pipe(imagemin())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img/@1x/'))
});
gulp.task('img2x', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/img/_src/**/*.*')
 .pipe(imageResize({ width: '100%' }))
 .pipe(imagemin())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img/@2x/'))
});

// Clean @*x IMG's
gulp.task('cleanimg', function() {
 return del(['app/img/@*'], { force:true })
});

// If Gulp Version 3
if (gulpVersion == 3) {

 // Img Processing Task for Gulp 3
 gulp.task('img', ['img1x', 'img2x']);
 
 var taskArr = ['styles', 'scripts', 'browser-sync'];
 gmWatch && taskArr.unshift('img');

 gulp.task('watch', taskArr, function() {
  gulp.watch('app/'+syntax+'/**/*.'+syntax+'', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', ['code']);
  gmWatch && gulp.watch('app/img/_src/**/*', ['img']);
 });
 gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

};

// If Gulp Version 4
if (gulpVersion == 4) {

 // Img Processing Task for Gulp 4
 gulp.task('img', gulp.parallel('img1x', 'img2x'));

 gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/'+syntax+'/**/*.'+syntax+'', gulp.parallel('styles'));
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], gulp.parallel('scripts'));
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', gulp.parallel('code'));
  gmWatch && gulp.watch('app/img/_src/**/*', gulp.parallel('img')); // GraphicsMagick watching image sources if allowed.
 });
 gmWatch ? gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('img', 'styles', 'scripts', 'browser-sync', 'watch')) 
     : gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts', 'browser-sync', 'watch'));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ничего, у gulp и php разные среды выполнения, можно подписаться на события изменения файлов от OS и перезапускать